# How to set up TightVNC Java viewer index.html on web server?

Tags: macos, website, vnc

I've got the Java TightVNC viewer applet set up with the provided index.html on my Mac OS X 10.6.3 with web sharing enabled.

Using a remote computer I was able to get to the webpage but I only see a white box with an X (for error?) that represents where the viewer is supposed to be. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

I've tried to set the port (in index.html) to 5900 and 5901, none worked. Are any of these the default VNC port for Mac OS X 10.6.3?

Also, I've activated Screen Sharing and Remote Login in System Preferences, allowing VNC viewers to connect.

Here is the code for my index.html:

```
<HTML>
<TITLE>
TightVNC desktop
</TITLE>
<APPLET CODE="classes/VncViewer.class" ARCHIVE="classes/VncViewer.jar"
        WIDTH="1440" HEIGHT="900">
<PARAM NAME="PORT" VALUE="5900">
<PARAM NAME="Scaling factor" VALUE="50">
</APPLET>
<BR>
<A href="http://www.tightvnc.com/">TightVNC site</A>
</HTML>
```

Again I can get to this page, but the applet doesn't seem to work, the Java console also doesn't say anything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<HTML>
<TITLE>
TightVNC desktop
</TITLE>
<APPLET CODE="/classes/VncViewer.class" ARCHIVE="/classes/VncViewer.jar"
        WIDTH="1440" HEIGHT="900">
<PARAM NAME="PORT" VALUE="5900">
<PARAM NAME="Scaling factor" VALUE="50">
</APPLET>
<BR>
<A href="http://www.tightvnc.com/">TightVNC site</A>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your HTML, but it doesn't work for me either...

I just get the red exclamation point and it says "An error has occurred."  Clicking "details" gives no details.

Is it possible to use this as standalone inside a browser?

Answer (score 1):

In TightVNC 2.2 there's an option "Serve Java Viewer to Web clients" and below there's a textfield for "Web access port": 5800 by default.

```
<PARAM NAME="PORT" VALUE="5800">
```

I've checked console and it said that I need to add parameter HOST. OK, I'll added:

```
<param name="HOST" value="172.25.150.147">
```

Now there's an **access denied (java.net.SocketPermission** exception. Lets sign applet to grant it rights to connect to VNC server, following steps described here:
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174214

I reloaded the page, saw a popup: do you trust this applet? Clicked **yes** and saw this applet working.